# MySQL IN statement using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im having the user filling checkboxes in my view for each year so that they can query based on selected years. The query is looking for a pH value between a minimum and maximum value.
As you can see there can be a variety of different years selected.

**View**

```
    @foreach($years as $year)

    {{ Form::checkbox('selectedYears[]', $year->year) }} {{ $year->year }}

    @endforeach
```

In my controller i then have something like this:

**Controller**

```
      $implodeYears = implode(', ',$input['selectedYears']);

      DB::select('SELECT samples.*, costumers.*
      FROM samples
      LEFT JOIN costumers
      ON samples.costumer_id = costumers.id
      WHERE
      pH            BETWEEN ? AND ?
      AND YEAR IN ( ? )
      Order BY Year DESC, samples.costumer_id DESC
      ', array(
        $minph,
        $maxph,
        $implodeYears
      ));
```

I checked my variable, and it seems to be fine:

```
    dd($implodeYears);
    string(34) "2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013"
```

The problem is that the query only returns the first year in the string. So i get that there is something wrong with this being a string.
When i query like this it works fine:

**Static years in controller**

```
  DB::select('SELECT samples.*, costumers.*
  FROM samples
  LEFT JOIN costumers
  ON samples.costumer_id = costumers.id
  WHERE
  pH            BETWEEN ? AND ?
  AND YEAR IN (2008, 2010, 2012)
  Order BY Year DESC, samples.costumer_id DESC
  ', array(
    $minph,
    $maxph
  ));
```

I have had this query working fine when i previously worked without Laravel. Thats the weird thing, and i get the exakt same thing in that version when var_dumping the imploded variable. Result below.

*Old Version with a standard MySQL query using var_dump*

```
 string(89) "1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014"
```

Is there someone who can give me a hint? 
Im shure there's a pretty good explanation for this. But i have googled for some time, and can't find it.

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you do not do something like that. The reason your code is currently returning only the first year is a combination of prepared statement misunderstanding, and typecasting.

When you do what you are doing there, the where part of the SQL query fired off to the server is equivalent to:

```
YEAR IN ("2008, 2009, 2010...")
```

As your field is most likely an integer, MySQL tries to understand/make sense of what you sent it, and transforms to this:

```
YEAR IN (2008)
```

This explains your first value.

## How to fix it

The short version is properly use the Laravel query builder. The following will work:

```
  DB::table('samples')
      ->select('samples.*', 'costumers.*')
      ->join('costumers', 'samples.costumer_id', '=', 'costumers.id')
      ->whereIn("samples.year", $input['selectedYears'])
      ->where("samples.pH", ">=", $minph)
      ->where("samples.pH", "<=", $maxph)
  ->get();
```

Pay very close attention; if the year list is empty, **this will fail** (but then again, so will yours)

Comment: Why first implode and then explode? ;) Also this is just the query builder and not Eloquent...

Comment: @lukasgeiter Corrected point 2 before you commented. As for the exploded list, I did not have his variable name. Decided to make it obvious what it was supposed to be.

Comment: See your code highlighting: 
`costumers.id')` missing starting quote: `'costumers.id')`

Comment: @Luceos Corrected, thank you! (Next time, don't feel the need to mention it and just edit :-) )

Comment: Sorry, 10 hour work day makes me forget obvious stuff @SébastienRenauld

Comment: Alright so i tried it, and i get this error: _Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 626 and defined_

There is surely i a nice answer, but i can't find it.. I hope this works! It is so much nicer than my old one.

Comment: @Simtrax `whereIn` expects an array.

Comment: @Sébastien-renauld

When checking debug in Laravel it seems to be an array?:
`min-ph 8.8
max-ph 8.9
selectedYears Array ( [0] => 2006 [1] => 2012 )`

Comment: @Simtrax I cannot reproduce the error using dummy code. However, some of the columns may be ambiguous in the select and where clauses. Will edit.

Comment: So of i to this `$test = DB::select('samples.*', 'costumers.*')
            ->from('samples')
            ->join('costumers', 'samples.costumer_id', '=', 'costumers.id')
            ->get();

        dd($test);`
I get the same error message, so there has to be something thats not working properly..

Comment: @Simtrax Let's clear out the basics. You're using laravel4 or laravel5 and you're running the latest `illuminate`, right?

Comment: Hold on, seems to be working now! Thanks!
Way better solution. I now use you're latest code with DB::table, not DB::select.